# Como mejorar mi expresion regular?

Tags: regex

tengo esta expresion regular

```
new Regex(@"^\b[A-Z a-z]+[(a-z)+(A-Z)+0-9]+$");
```

quiero que mi cadena permita iniciar con letras mayusculas o minusculas, pero no con otros caracteres, esta bien que ponga `A-Z a-z` ?

ahora tambien como puedo restringir el tamano de mi cadena?

Answer (score 1):

```
\b[A-Z a-z]+[(a-z)+(A-Z)+0-9]+
```

- No está claro que se supone que hace el \b.
- Tienes un espacio en blanco entre *A-Z* y *a-z*. No es necesario, lo único que hace es permitirte también espacios en blanco. Pásalo a *[A-Za-z]*. Además, si tu lenguaje lo soporta, lo puedes cambiar por *[:alpha:]*.
- Si el primer grupo solo es para el primer carácter, el *+* sobra. Ya te sirve con el *+* del segundo grupo.
- No veo muy claro porqué los paréntesis y los "+" dentro de la expresión, cuando lo que tienes que hacer es idéntico al primer grupo (más el *0-9*): *[a-zA-Z0-9]+*. O, si el lenguage lo soporta, *[:alnum:]*
- Para la longitud, el primer grupo no tiene "+" así que solo te identifica un caracter. Puedes usar *{}* para indicar repeticiones de un grupo, que en este caso sería el segundo:

  - {7} indica que son necesarias 7 repeticiones. Así, *[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]{7}* necesita una longitud de 8 (un carácter válido para el primer grupo, 7 caracteres válidos para el segundo).
  - {3,7} indica que son necesarias entre 3 y 7 repeticiones.
  - {,7} indica que se identifican hasta 7 repeticiones.
  - {7,} indican que son necesarias como mínimo 7 repeticiones.

En todo caso, como en tu expresión tienes el caracter inicial ^ y final $, esta expresión te hace match de toda la cadena. Con lo cual, también te basta poner *[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]+* y controlar la longitud del string sin usar expresiones regulares.

https://www.regular-expressions.info/refcharclass.html

Comment: \b ->  Any word boundary